# How to extract specific information from pandas column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is the `posdf`:

```
      tradingsymbol
0     XYZ2061820500PE
1     XYZ20JUN21000PE
2     ABC20JUN100CE
3    ABC20JUN102.5PE
4     ABC20JUN92.5PE
4     XYZ20JUNFUT
```

I am doing this to extract the `ABC` and `XYZ` to a column:

```
posdf['symbol'] = posdf['tradingsymbol'].str.extract('^(\D+)', expand=True)
```

I cannot figure out how I can make a generalised way to extract the following columns:

```
     strike    type   Expiry
0    20500     PE     20618
1    21000     PE     20JUN
2    100       CE     20JUN
3    102.5     PE     20JUN
4    92.5      PE     20JUN
4    NA        FUT    20JUN
```

### Edit

`type` is min 2 chars max 3.
`Expiry` is always 5 chars. Which could possibly have this form: `20O18` or `20N18` or `20D18`.

### 2nd Edit

Adding rows where `type` can be 3 chars based on Sammy's comment.

Comment: are `type` and `Expiry` always 2 and 5 chars long?

Comment: I think you are on to sth Stef; probably try it out  and see if your idea holds

Comment: Type can be min 2, max 3. Expiry is always 5 chars. Should Have mentioned.

Comment: I'd suggest @Sid, that you add rows where type can be three characters long; your current dataframe fits only two characters for type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a given `regex` pattern:

```
df1 = df['tradingsymbol'].str.extract(
    r'(?P<expiry>\d{5}|\d{2}\w{3})(?P<strike>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?P<type>\w+)')
df1 = df1[['strike', 'type', 'expiry']]
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
  strike type expiry

0  20500   PE  20618
1  21000   PE  20JUN
2    100   CE  20JUN
3  102.5   PE  20JUN
4   92.5   PE  20JUN
4    NaN  FUT  20JUN
```

You can test the regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/ZJq1rV/4).

Answer (score 3):

if Strike is always numerical then you can do:

```
posdf[['Symbol','Expiry','Strike','Type']] = posdf['tradingsymbol'].str.extract('^(\D+)(.{5})([0-9.]*)([a-zA-Z]{2,3})', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
     tradingsymbol Symbol Expiry Strike Type
0  XYZ2061820500PE    XYZ  20618  20500   PE
1  XYZ20JUN21000PE    XYZ  20JUN  21000   PE
2    ABC20JUN100CE    ABC  20JUN    100   CE
3  ABC20JUN102.5PE    ABC  20JUN  102.5   PE
4   ABC20JUN92.5PE    ABC  20JUN   92.5   PE
4      XYZ20JUNFUT    XYZ  20JUN         FUT
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a hack :

```
res = (df.assign(Expiry = df.tradingsymbol.str[3:8],
                 type = df.tradingsymbol.str[8:].str.split("([a-zA-Z]+)").str[1],
                 strike = df.tradingsymbol.str[8:].str.split("[a-zA-Z]+").str[0],
                )
      )

res


   tradingsymbol    Expiry  type    strike
0   XYZ2061820500PE 20618   PE      20500
1   XYZ20JUN21000PE 20JUN   PE      21000
2   ABC20JUN100CE   20JUN   CE      100
3   ABC20JUN102.5PE 20JUN   PE      102.5
4   ABC20JUN92.5PE  20JUN   PE      92.5
4   XYZ20JUNFUT     20JUN   FUT
```